# Is linear convolution same thing as aperiodic convolution?

Tags: convolution, terminology

I am reading an online article and what i understood from there is that linear convolution is aperiodic
Is it right?

I have also attached snapshot and higlighted two instances

[image]

Answer (score 3, accepted):

What they call *noncircular* or *aperiodic* convolution is more commonly called *linear convolution*. Linear convolution describes the input-output relation of linear time-invariant (LTI) systems. Linear convolution can be computed via circular convolution if we use sufficient zero-padding. Circular convolution is important because it can be computed using fast algorithms (FFT).